# SQL Server 2008 native SQL password recovery

Tags: sql-server-2008, passwords, password-recovery

I have a situation where I need to determine the password of a database user in SQL Server 2008 (not R2, just regular 2008). It is a native SQL Server account, and has no password restrictions / policies assigned to it. I have full sysadmin access on the SQL Server already; under normal circumstances I would simply reset the password for this user (it is NOT the `sa` user) to a known value, however the account is used for a variety of processes as is, and cannot be changed; unfortunately, the existing password was not documented anywhere, and nobody knows what it is.

I have found a number of different ways to do this in SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005, but none of them appear to work in SQL Server 2008. Note, the user is indeed active, and in fact its credentials are actually saved in the SQL Server Management Studio, where I can log in with the SQL Server user whose password I need to obtain -- so, I *know* that the account is good. I just need to find out what the password is!  :P

Thanks very much!

Comment: And none of those processes have the password stored in a config file, or in the pre-compiled code in source control, or can be retrieved using reflector or similar approaches? There are also apps you should be able to find that will show you the text behind masked passwords (like the one in the SSMS dialog).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the official position is to reset the password, which I know you don't want to do.  Beyond that I believe you're stuck trying out 3rd party applications that claim to have this ability, but none guarantee success.  Of course, passwords are supposed to be hard to discover...